# Is it possible to get Android Fingerprint hashcode?

Tags: android, keystore, fingerprint, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api

Is it possible to get Android Fingerprint hashcode ? Or can I get any kind of unique information fingerprint to send it to server and use it for future comparing ?

And also can anyone sugest a good documentation for Fingerprint and Keysore ( Google's official one is not so clear ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get Android Fingerprint hashcode ?

No, sorry.

> Or can I get any kind of unique information fingerprint to send it to server and use it for future comparing ?

If you mean "for future comparing" with fingerprints collected from some other device, no, sorry.

Comment: Hello and thanks for an answer ! So as far as I understood, the fingerprint provides only one time verification ( it is returning boolean have the user passed fingerprint verification or not ) and that's it, nothing else, am I right ?

Comment: @abrutsze: Correct. Using the `AndroidKeyStore`, you can also have device authentication (such as a fingerprint) control access to encryption/decryption, but that only works for on-device data.